# Getting error 406 from Facebooker API on Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

My app was working fine with Rails 2.2 and Facebooker 1.0.13, but I keep getting a 406 error with Rails 2.3.
I checked the mime type, canvas/iframe setting in Facebook, and the requests work fine outside of Facebook (i.e. I get the full app as long as I'm not accessing it within the Facebook iframe). Has something changed recently in the Facebook API that would cause this error? Or is there anything in Facebooker that you've found might be fixed quickly?

Here is my Dev log for reference:

`Processing PostsController#index (for xx.xxx.xx.xxx at 2009-03-06 03:24:44) [GET]
  Parameters: {"fb_sig_app_id"=>"xxxxx",

   "fb_sig_in_iframe"=>"1",

   "fb_sig_locale"=>"en_US", 
   "fb_sig_in_new_facebook"=>"1",

   "fb_sig"=>"xxxxx",

   "fb_sig_added"=>"1",

   "fb_sig_expires"=>"xxxxx",

   "fb_sig_session_key"=>"xxxxx",

   "fb_sig_ss"=>"xxxxx",

   "fb_sig_api_key"=>"xxxxx",

   "fb_sig_time"=>"1236327886.7997",

   "fb_sig_profile_update_time"=>"1228275036",

   "fb_sig_user"=>"11111"}

  User Columns (6.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM users
  User Load (1.0ms)   SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.login = 11111) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)   BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)   COMMIT
  Competition Load (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM posts`

#### Completed in 135ms (View: 8, DB: 8) | 406 Not Acceptable

[http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/?fb_sig_in_iframe=1&
fb_sig_locale=en_US&
fb_sig_in_new_facebook=1&
fb_sig_time=xxxxx.xxxxx&
fb_sig_added=1&
fb_sig_profile_update_time=1228275036&
fb_sig_expires=xxxxx&
fb_sig_user=xxxxx&
...]

If more details are needed, I'll be glad to give them...:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the Facebook Forums:

http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=93648#p93648

Sorry for implying that Facebooker wasn't working correctly...What you're doing is GREAT Michael (et al), keep up the great work!